# I have a var in as3 and I want to get its name in a string

Tags: actionscript-3

Example:

```
public var myVar:Object;
// now I want to get the myVar string
// myVar is not instanced*
public var whatINeedIsThisVar:String = 'myVar';
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that, and when you are working in release mode (i.e. not debuuging a swf)  local variable name didn't exist anymore.

But if it's a public field name of a class you can use [describeType](http://www.insideria.com/2009/09/as3-reflection-using-describet.html) to found the name.

```
package {
 import flash.utils.describeType;

 class Foo extends Sprite {
  public var bar:Object;

  function Foo(){
   super();
   // trace all public field name in this class
   for each (variable:XML in describeType(this).variable) {
    trace("field name : ", variable.@name);
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: yes it's a public var in a class. is a skinPart.
But I heard that is heavy to rely on describeType, right?
Now I have found the .id but only works when instanced

Comment: @Totty If you can specify a little bit on what you want achieve, maybe there is a solution.

Comment: "when you are working in release mode, local variable name didn't exist anymore". This is somewhat true, except there must be a lookup table to the variable names somewhere because you can access variables through string like so: this["bar"]. This does not mean YOU have access to the names though

Comment: @TandemAdam, no LOCAL VARIABLE are just compiled as an integer index representing the position of the register holding the variable, but as i said you can access public CLASS MEMBER with describeType for example. Your this["bar"] is just accessing such a field.

Comment: ok, thanks everybody. i have to try another way around. thanks anyway ;) how to close this question?