# get string of variable name in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Does anyone know some ActionScript api to get String of a variable name like following:

```
var foo:int;
var variableName:String = getName(foo);
trace(variableName);
```

The console need to show "foo" as the result of `trace(variableName);`

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781209/as3-i-have-a-var-in-as3-and-i-want-to-get-its-name-in-a-string/3781635#3781635

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Yes, now I find out it's duplicate question. Sorry.

Comment: See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437580/get-string-representation-of-a-variable-name-in-as3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with this?

flash.utils.describeType can help find the name/types of any variables of an object but I don't think it will give you the instance name. I believe most of that information is lost when you compile the code so getting it at runtime will be rather difficult.

Comment: Thank you, mixFM. I totally agree with your answer.