# get string representation of a variable name in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

any way of doing this is as3?

for example, if I have a `var dog:String`, how can I get "dog" out of that variable?

Looking into reflection to do this, but there's got to be an easier way

--
A

Comment: Does this make sense? Because the var name is not important. If it is then you should probably use some kind of object key/value map. Also what do you expect to get if you do 
`var dog:String;
var cat:String = dog;`

Comment: It does.... i'd like to find a way to automatically map XML node values to a VO class's public propeties

Comment: Seems like you are asking the wrong question. You might have better luck in asking what you want to achieve, rather than asking this kind of question. An example might be "How can you automatically map XML node values to a VO class's public properties?"

Comment: now way to do this without reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
class A {
   var dog:String = "something";
   var cat:String = "eatdog";
}

function getVars(obj:*):void
{
    for(var i:* in obj){
        trace( i + " : " + obj[i]);
        // this will trace all properties of object.
        // dog : somthing
        // cat : eatdog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all if it's an instance of a custom class, you can override the `toString()` method.
- If it's a property of the class, you can use this method — https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3781635/revisions
- If it's a local variable, there is no way to get that name.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't want to "get" the string representation of a variable name, but rather set the variable based on a string.

To set a variable that you have its name as a string you can do this:

```
this['dog'] = 'value of the dog var';
```

Comment: `+1` Just note this won't work unless `this` is `dynamic` (or has the property `dog`).

Answer (score 0):

In your example I don't think there is a way to retrieve "dog" as a String.

However, if `dog` is a property of a `dynamic` Object, then you could use a function like this:

```
function getVarName(subject:*, value:*):String
{
    for(var i:String in subject)
    {
        if(subject[i] == value) return i;
    }

    return "";
}
```

This function can work in a scenario like this:

```
var holder:Object = {
    dog: "some awesome dog"
}

trace(getVarName(holder, "some awesome dog")); // dog
```