# sortOn function with priorities

Tags: java, javascript, algorithm, actionscript-3, sorting

I was wondering if how to create a custom sortOn function, with some sort of sort-priorities. I have a more complex case, but I'm mostly wondering how to build nice sort functions.

Lets say I have this unsorted list with data objects:

```
var myList = [
 {drink: {amount: 1, name: "cola"}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 5, name: "beer"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 7, name: "cake"}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 3, name: "fanta"}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 4, name: "tea}}, 
 {other: {amount: 1, name: "table"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 4, name: "mars"}},
 {food: {amount: 5, name: "pizza"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 4, name: "cake"}}, 
 {other: {amount: 12, name: "chair"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 14, name: "chips"}},
 {drink: {amount: 6, name: "coffee}}, 
 {food: {amount: 8, name: "chips"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 6, name: "pizza"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 1, name: "food"}} 
]
```

Ok, imaging I want sort using these rules:

```
first: sort in this order: food, drinks, others (note, thats not alphabetical)
  then: sort on amount, BUT on food, pizza's + cakes must be on top
```

In the ideal case it would look like this (manually created):

```
var myList = [
 {food: {amount: 5, name: "pizza"}},
 {food: {amount: 6, name: "pizza"}},
 {food: {amount: 4, name: "cake"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 7, name: "cake"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 1, name: "food"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 4, name: "mars"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 8, name: "chips"}}, 
 {food: {amount: 14, name: "chips"}},
 {drink: {amount: 1, name: "cola"}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 3, name: "fanta"}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 4, name: "tea}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 5, name: "beer"}}, 
 {drink: {amount: 6, name: "coffee}}, 
 {other: {amount: 1, name: "table"}}, 
 {other: {amount: 12, name: "chair"}}
]
```

Again, this is totally not a real-world example, but I have cases with (even deeper nested objects) where I want to apply such rules.

Would it be possible to create some sort order look-up list (something like this), or is that not feasible?

```
priorityList = [
              food:[
                 name:["pizza", "tea", rest], 
                 amount: Array.ASCENDING}
                ], 
              drink, 
              other
          ]; // etc..
```

I want to learn how to make such kind of sort functions. I love to see a Javascript or Actionscript solution but other languages to illustrate are okay too. Is there a library for this? Do I have to loop through all items, create conditions, push/unshift in cases or is this possible with a custom `sort()` function? I need some directions how to solve this in a practical/efficient way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function takes a comparator argument. It's a function that compares two elements of the list, sort() then does the rest.

Comment: @ajax333221 I fixed the cola, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that you'll have to return -1, 0, or 1 but it doesn't mean you cant handle your complex sorting inside it, though it'd mean you'd have to custom code for every case you encountered. Something like this would work:

```
function myCustomSort(firstObject, secondObject):int 
{
    // Is firstObject a food and the second not? firstObject goes in front. 
    // Are both objects a food?
        // Is firstObject's name pizza and the second not? 
        // firstObject goes in front. 
        //Are both objects' names pizza? Return 0 - they're equivalent.
    //ETC.
}
```

Ideally though you'd want to support something like that schema you gave as the example. I'd recommend making the structure the same at the root as it is in the child (so you can run the same code on every level), your example would then look something like:

```
priorityList = {
                    "consumingType":[
                      "food":{
                         "name":[
                            "pizza", 
                            "tea"
                            ], 
                         amount: Array.ASCENDING
                        }, 
                      "drink", 
                      "other"
                    ], 
                    amount: Array.ASCENDING
                };
```

The actual solution may differ slightly depending on actual structure (whether your data is in JSON, or Objects) and what language - but here's a starter in AS3 **that I haven't tested**; that should point you in the right direction.

Firstly, I'd write a recursive sort function that handles one layer of the sorting, then checks if there's a child layer or returns:

```
function handleComplexSorting( sortingObject, first, second ) {
    var result:int = 0;
    //Extracting the property name of first/second will differ, 
    //but pretty sure this is how you do it in AS3.
    var firstValue:int = findSortValueForProperty(first[0], sortingObject[0]);
    var secondValue:int = findSortValueForProperty(second[0], sortingObject[0]);

    if( firstValue > secondValue ) {
        //firstValue should go first.
        result = -1;
    }
    else if(firstValue < secondValue){
        //secondValue should go first.
        result = 1;
    }
    else {//equal
        var childSortingObject:Object;
        if( hasChildSorting(sortingObject, childSortingObject) ){
            //return result of recursion
            result = handleComplexSorting(childSortingObject, first, second);
        }
        else {
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The findSortValueForProperty function would be where you'd add the ascending/descending, I've left it out, but you'd just need to check which one and invert the result value. The value here is determined by the inverse of its index in the array (first appearing has highest value, last has lowest, not there - 0 value).

```
function findSortValueForProperty(property:String, priorityProperties:Array):int {
    var resultValue:int = 0;
    var index = 0;
    for each( var currentProperty:String in priorityProperties ) {
        if(property == currentProperty) {
            resultValue = priorityProperties.length - index;
            break;
        }
        ++index;
    }
    return resultValue;
}
```

Finally, a check to see if the object has child sorting requirements. This actually won't work, it only expects the first item to maybe have child-sorting. I'm also not 100% that you can access an Object's variables by index like I am (`sortingObject[0]`) (you can definitely iterate over them though).

```
function hasChildSorting(sortingObject:Object, outChild:Object):Boolean {
    var result:Boolean = false;
        if( sortingObject[0] is Object ) {
            result = true;
            outChild = sortingObject[0];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For AS3 specifically see [get string representation of a variable name in as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437580/get-string-representation-of-a-variable-name-in-as3) for accessing variables by string.
You'll also need your language to have [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) if you want to do it in something else.

Comment: I specifically did not say "easiest solution is to create a custom sort function"!  The easiest solution is to create a custom *compare* function, which is much easier, and then use the built-in sort function.

Comment: Also, @Mark Kool: I'm referring to sort as though its sorting between two objects (ie. comparing). My whole answer is a custom comparison function.

Comment: This is already very useful, have to study this and make it work myself. Thanks for this in-depth answer; it's a very good start!

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the two problems in your mind.

One is *sorting*: given a list of comparable objects, sort them from "lowest" to "highest".  This is a totally solved problem.  Don't worry about it.

The other is *comparison*: given two objects, which is "first"?  Given that specification you wrote, and any two objects, A and B, can you say -1 (object A is first), 0 (they're equivalent for sorting purposes), or 1 (object B is first).

Write that function (in your favorite language) and pass it to the language's built-in sorting library to get fast sort.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. But I think the problem of my question lies in the fact I want to mix both. I am aware of the sort function of my language, but I have totally no idea how to deal with multiple comparison rules AND sorting inside one sort-function. So I have no idea when I should pass -1, 0 or 1. Most examples on the web compare only 1 property, not such specific sorting.

Comment: You do *not* want to mix both.  Sorting depends on (and depends *entirely* on) ordering.  You have to be able to reduce the problem to comparing just two objects.